# text not getting displayed in a inflated layout android for some devices

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I am having a confused scenario, U have inflated a layout and it works fine for few devices and the text does not show up for few devices.
For Example: it works fine in Moto G3, but the same is not work g in Asus Zenfone 01.

Here is my getView() method:

```
 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unavailable_friend_adapter_row, null);
    }
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.rowImage);
    TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    Log.d("Value of position is ", ""+position);
    Log.d("Value of Text is ", ""+getItem(position).name);
    if (position == 0) {
        text.setText("Send mail...");
        text.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).drawable);
        text.setText(getItem(position).name);
    }
    return v;
}
```

Please let me know why is this happening

Comment: Try removing `View v = convertView;` and use `convertView` in place of `v`

Comment: Also change this line to match `inflater.inflate(R.layout.unavailable_friend_adapter_row, parent, false);

Comment: @HariLamichhane tried not working

Comment: Can you post your full code of `adapter` ?